# The language files of wordpress keeps deleting automatically after an hours of uploading

Tags: wordpress

The language file located in wp-content/languages keeps deleting automatically after uploading is there any one knows how to solve this issue , thank you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was from the automatic update of WordPress and plugins. Problem solved after disabling the automatic updates.